# Collapse all trees in jquery checkboxtree

Tags: jquery, user-interface, checkbox, tree

I use [jquery checkboxtree](http://code.google.com/p/checkboxtree/) and I would like to start tree in collapsed mode.

I use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ch_group_menu').checkboxTree();
});
```

I will tree and all childs collapsed at start. How Can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

`$('#ch_group_menu').checkboxTree('collapse','.expanded');`

after your form generated and checkboxTree will applied.